# finalize with flatMap in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular 5 and rxjs. I am making 2 service calls, one dependent on others results. I am doing it using flatMap. I also want to do some operation after both api calls have been made. I am using finalize for it. My code looks like below:

```
this.myservice.api1(param1).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$), finalize(() => {
//do something after both api calls are completed
},
flatMap((result1) => {
    //do some operation and create object x(this.objx)
    return this.myservice.api2(param1);
})
).subscribe((result2) => {
    //do something based on result2 and this.objx
})
```

The finalize block however is getting executed after first API call only. With one API call finalize is getting executed but with flatMap it gets executed only after first API call. Please let me know if I am mistaking anything.

Comment: `finalize` would be called before `this.myservice.api2(param1)` only if `this.myservice.api1(param1)` errors or if `this.destroyed$` emits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `this.myservice.api1(param1)` is normal http request and it emits just once and then completes.

I would suggest to use `switchMap` for this:

```
this.myservice
    .api1(param1)
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
        switchMap((result1) => {
            //do some operation and create object x(this.objx)
            return this.myservice.api2(param1);
        }),
        finalize(() => {
            //do something after both api calls are completed
        },
    ).subscribe((result2) => {
        //do something based on result2 and this.objx
    })
```

Finalize will be called when the chain completes or errors.

Comment: It worked after I put finalize function after flatMap function. Thanks!